# LMM on Chickweight data

Tags: r

I would like to write a model with random intercepts and random slopes with respect to time. I am not sure if my code is correct.

```
model4<-lmer(weight~Time + Diet + Time*Diet + (1+Time|Chick), data = Data, REML = TRUE)
summary(model4)
```

Comment: I voted to migrate this question over to cross validated.  It seems more closely a question about the appropriate statistical test to use, than it is a question about programming.

Comment: @dww There seems to be cross-posting as well as virtually the same questions appear on CV but are phrased a bit differently, eg. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/568349/237901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct specification for those random effects. You can check this out, by applying a similar model, but temporarily removing the fixed effect on diet and the interaction between time and diet

```
model4<-lmer(weight~Time + (1+Time|Chick), data = ChickWeight, REML = TRUE)
```

Column bind the original data, plus predictions from this simple model above, and select five random Chicks to plot

```
weight_hat = predict(model4)
cw = cbind(ChickWeight,weight_hat)
random_chicks = sample(unique(cw$Chick),5)

ggplot(cw[cw$Chick %in% random_chicks,], aes(Time, color=Chick)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=weight), size=2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=weight_hat), size=1.5) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  guides(color=guide_legend(nrow=1))
```

You can see that the intercept and slope for each Chick differs.
[image: chicks]